# How to handle parsing of multiple ranges and individual numbers?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to take in values like so:

```
test2.sh switchname unicast [IgnorePort]
```

`IgnorePort` has ranges beneath it such as `1-8,12,34,37-43`
or any variations like that. How would I handle that sort of parsing into an array or into individual values

I've been googling it and haven't been able to find anything although I feel like this would be something everyone would have to learn at some point in time.

## currently have to do:

```
test2.sh switchname unicast 1
test2.sh switchname unicast 2
test2.sh switchname unicast 3
test2.sh switchname unicast 10
```

## want to do:

```
test2.sh switchname unicast 1-3,10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert that range of numbers into a list, try:

```
awk -F- -v RS=, '{print $1} NF==2{for (i=$1+1;i<=$2;i++)print i}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo 1-3,5,9-10 | awk -F- -v RS=, '{print $1} NF==2{for (i=$1+1;i<=$2;i++)print i}'
1
2
3
5
9
10
```

Or, to use in a script:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(echo "$3" | awk -F- -v RS=, '{print $1} NF==2{for (i=$1+1;i<=$2;i++)print i}')
do
    echo "Working on $i"
done
```

As an example of running the above script:

```
$ bash script switchname unicast 1-2,11,20-21
Working on 1
Working on 2
Working on 11
Working on 20
Working on 21
```

#### How it works

awk reads in one record at a time.  Each record is split into fields.  In our case, we will treat `,` as the record separator.  Thus, when reading in, for example, `1-3,5,9-10`, the first record that awk sees is `1-3` and this record has two fields `1`, and `3`.  The second record is `5` and so on.  Each record is processed in turn.

- `-F-`

  This tells awk to use `-` as the field separator
- `-v RS=,`

  This tells awk to use `,` as the record separator.
- `print $1`

  This tells awk to print the first field.
- `NF==2{for (i=$1+1;i<=$2;i++)print i}`

  If there are two fields in the record, then print the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to accept a list of individual number rather than ranges you would have to parse. `bash` can easily generate the individual numbers for you using brace expansion.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Sketch of your script test2.sh when accepting arbitrary many individual numbers

switchname="$1"
unicast="$2"
shift 2
ports=("$@")

# do something, for instance ...
for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
    # something
done
```

Then call your script as follows to emulate the range `1-8,12,34,37-43`

```
test2.sh switchname unicast {{1..8},12,34,{37..43}}
```

If you really want to specify ranges the next easier thing to do would be to transform the range into a brace pattern and `eval` that one. Keep in mind that this can result in code injection if you mess up the input validation.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Sketch of your script test2.sh when accepting one range

switchname="$1"
unicast="$2"
range="$3"
if ! [[ range =~ ^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*$ ]]; then
    echo "Illegal range expression: $range"
    exit 1
fi
bracePattern="{$(sed -E 's/([^,]+)-([^,]+)/{\1..\2}/g' <<< "$range")}"
eval "ports=($bracePattern)"

# do something, just like in the first version of the script
```

Answer (score 0):

the following function will echo each number in the range(s)

```
function ranger {
        A=$(echo $1 | tr "," " ")
        for a in $A
        do
                if [[ $a == *"-"* ]]; then
                        B=( $(echo $a | tr "-" " ") )
                        x=${B[0]}
                        y=${B[1]}
                        for z in $(seq ${B[0]} ${B[1]})
                        do
                                echo $z
                        done
                else
                        echo $a
                fi
        done
}
```

so modify test2.sh similar to this

```
function test2 {
    for i in $(ranger $3)
    do
        #execute test2.sh code
    done
}
```

and then run 
`$ test2.sh switchname unicast 1,2,5-7`